# Error during deployment after App Engine upgrade

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying deploy an app from Windows 7 x64. I have App Engine SDK 1.9.20 installed and ActivePython 2.7.8.10. Here is the output of appcfg.py:

```
03:39 PM Application: turnkey-antler-289; version: 1
03:39 PM Host: appengine.google.com
03:39 PM
Starting update of app: turnkey-antler-289, version: 1
03:39 PM Getting current resource limits.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5475, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5466, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3023, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5122, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3860, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3913, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3798, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2444, in DoUpload
    self.error_fh)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 490, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(_GetRemoteResourceLimits(logging_context))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 460, in _GetRemoteResourceLimits
    yaml_data = logging_context.Send('/api/appversion/getresourcelimits')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1746, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 230, in Send
    self._Authenticate(self.http, auth_errors[0] > 0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 439, in _Authenticate
    self.credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, self.storage, self.flags)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_flow'
```

Now, everything was working fine until I upgraded App Engine SDK and I did that in order to switch the app to php55 runtime. I would like to hear any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrading your App Engine SDK while you mentioned that you have App Engine SDK 1.9.20 installed ? As far as I know, the latest Cloud SDK is 1.9.20.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on a clean Win7 + ActivePython + SDK 1.9.20. Could you try reinstalling the SDK?

Comment: Same problem win7+py2.7.

Comment: I had older version installed, the problem started after upgrade to latest version. Already tried reinstalling, it didn't help.

Comment: Are you running appcfg directly or through the launcher?

Comment: @Mars He mentioned that he is running appcfg.py directly and get the output above.

Comment: It seems you're getting the same error as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199807/deploy-error-on-gae-launcher-1-9-20

Comment: @Jun right, that is the same error.

Yes, I am running appcgf.py directly. I installed 1.9.20 on ubuntu machine yesterday and there deployment of the same apps works just fine. But I'd still like to get it working on Win7.

Comment: Can you try manually remove the file <home>/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens, then run "appcfg.py update" without any extra flags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem... Here I share you the solution that worked for me:

1. On Windows OS, Go to the "Control Panel" > "Programs & Features" and unistall all the versions of GAE you have.
2. Go to the path where you had GAE installed, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google" in your case, and delete the folder "google_appengine" (if you prefer you can do a backup)
3. Install the lastest version of GAE (1.9.20 actually)
4. Test to deploy your apps, should work now.